# daterangepicker is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, daterangepicker

I am referring this fiddle. `http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2213/` I want like this daterangepicker but unable to do so... please have a look anyone.... 
[image: My code screenshot that I posted in question...]

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#e1").daterangepicker({});

   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.3.1/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
    <input id="e1" name=e1 />
   </div>
```

Comment: Well where is jQuery and jQuery ui sources? Error is clear as day in the above snipplet: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @epascarello I am referring fiddle..... in fiddle, it was not there.... that's why I didn't put in my code...

Comment: Well put it in the snipplet so we do not need to go to another random site. Your screenshot of the IDE does not show the jQuery includes either so not sure how it would work there if jquery is not included in the page.

Comment: ok bro give me a minute

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohsinshaikh/o7b42294/ my fiddle

Comment: And if you look at your console you get: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js:700
(index):27 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at window.onload ((index):27)`

Comment: ya ya exactly same error i also tried comiseo file in code but same error

Comment: @epascarello how to rid of this error ? any solution bro

Comment: Um, include jQuery library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more correct than the solution you are using:

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

You also need to import jQuery as the above comment mentioned

Comment: no no you are not getting the question please visit on fiddle that i posted on question

Comment: No problem, you need have an id which is called datepicker or some other name like `button id="crossClick" > </button>` then you can change `$("#datepicker')` to `$("#crossClick')`

Comment: i want to use daterangepicker not datepicker

Comment: Oh I see. are you referring to this one? 
http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/

Comment: First what is not working? I am not really able to reproduce this?

Comment: Demon the code i pasted is not working.. when you click on input box the daterangepicker will not pop out :(

Comment: did you do what the above comment with the other users?